# Is 集まろう！ a common way to say "Let's get together?"

Tags: meaning

I'm pretty sure 集{あつ}まろう (atsumarou) technically means "Let's get together" or "Let's gather together" i.e. as a group, but I'm not sure if this would be a commonly used phrase in real-world Japanese.  Are there any particular contexts in which this would make more sense or be more common?

Comment: More common than what?

Comment: More common than some other situation e.g. maybe this would be ok, but not common, for one friend to say to another but maybe it would be common to say in an office setting to a group of people talking about an after work get together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that in real-world Japanese, 集まろう is a very popular and commonly used phrase in a group of people, in the context such as いつもの飲み屋に集まろう or あの公園に集まろう or 名古屋で集まろう or ホテルで集まろう. In other words, 集まろう is usually preceded by the phrase (場所)に or (場所)で in daily conversation. Therefore the phrase 集まろう without the reference to the gathering place is used in very restricted situations, e.g. in advertisement, or chorus of shouts (you put ! after 集まろう), in an office setting to a group of people, with the mutual knowledge of the gathering place, talking about an after work get together. Last of all, I have to make one additional but important remark about this expression, 集まろう is an expression almost for males, and more polite form of 集まりましょう is preferred especially by females.

Comment: Thanks so much for the great answer! I was asking this question because I'm working on a project to make a multi-lingual (English and Japanese initially) social networking platform so regular people can create small social networking sites, focused on a specific topic, without knowing how to code. I am brainstorming names for the platform / site and thought Atsumarou.com might be kind of cool since, well, social networking sites are about getting together. Based on your answer, it seems like it might indeed be a good name for my project. Thanks again!

Comment: I'd be careful about saying 集まろう is for men and 集まりましょう is for women, though. 集まりましょう is just a more polite way of saying 集まろう. Men would use it too when speaking to their bosses or seniors at work, it's more a matter of familiarity/closeness between the speaker and the listener than a gender thing.

Comment: Deeeeekun, thank you very much for your comment. I should have been more careful about  asserting this or that from a gender point of view.

Comment: I know language evolves, but it still makes me mad when I learn that "men say it this way, be careful, only men say it this way. Women say it like this, which is also the more polite way to say it." Screw that! Seriously. This 'men have the freedom to say it this way not women' B. S. is, I know, part of the culture, but perhaps equality could start here. (This is the comment I'm referring to, and in no way an criticizing what they said, it's very helpful and necessary to point out BUT I'm asking, shouldn't we do our part to help society evolve? These are barriers imposed upon humans that need

Comment: The plain volitional is used by women *all the time*, in both real life and fiction

Answer (score 2):

集まろう does mean "Let's get together". But in the context you posted ("after work get-together"), I more commonly hear "集合しよう". Also, I think it's more common to actually indicate what will be done (i.e. "飲みに行こう", "ご飯行こう", "遊ぼう"). "集合しよう" would be used when indicating a specific time, date, or place.

Comment: `Also, I think it's more common to actually indicate what will be done` I agree, this seems like a better answer pertaining to a social scenario.